# Leaving out plots in gridspec - Why does my figsize change?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I'm using [gridspec](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/intermediate/gridspec.html) from matplotlib to have a way to set up subplots with a fixed layout, but I don't get why it behaves as it does.

Let's say I want to have this plot here:

[image: plot1]

done with

```
fig = plt.figure(constrained_layout=True, figsize=(12,6))#
gs = fig.add_gridspec(7,7)
leftplot = fig.add_subplot(gs[0:-1,0:-2])
topright = fig.add_subplot(gs[0:3,-1])
topmiddle = fig.add_subplot(gs[0:3,-2:-1])
botmiddle = fig.add_subplot(gs[3:6,-2:-1])
botright = fig.add_subplot(gs[3:6,-1])
botplot = fig.add_subplot(gs[-1,:])
plt.savefig('test1.png')
```

(why the hell do the axes overlap? Doesn't do that with my real data…)

Now not all of the small boxes in the top right corner need to be filled, depending on the data.
I figured I just plot only the boxes I need, and since it's a fixed layout, there should be simply empty space (So the plot statement above is set up with a few `if`s in there).
At the extreme, there might be only one box in the top right, like so:

```
fig = plt.figure(constrained_layout=True, figsize=(12,6))
gs = fig.add_gridspec(7,7)
leftplot = fig.add_subplot(gs[0:-1,0:-2])
topright = fig.add_subplot(gs[0:3,-1])
botplot = fig.add_subplot(gs[-1,:])
plt.savefig('test2.png')
```

However, it doesn't really look as expected:

[image: plot2]

First, the size changed, even though I specified that with `figsize` (the png file done with `plt.savefig` has the same dimensions though, just with huge padding around the figure).

Second, the topright plot appears to still be in the correct column, but the rows now seems to stretch `[0:5]` or `[0:6]` instead of the `[0:3]` I specified.

**Why is this happening, even though I have fixed all positions with gridspec?**

Comment: possibly because of `constrained_layout=True`. That will move things around to try and fit them in what it thinks is "best" to the figure space. Try removing that and see if it helps?

Comment: This appears to work, however, I need `constrained_layout` for other things in the figure. Can `constrained_layout` override the positioning and not just the spacing?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know; I find it often easier to define the spacing between subplots, and the margins between subplots and the edge of the plot, using `fig.subplots_adjust()` and defining the top, bottom, left, right, wspace and hspace in there.